# what is the main purpose of codigniter session database

Tags: codeigniter

I can't understand what is the main pupose of this session database, while we can get and set cookies with cookie helper , and when we really use codeigniter session, we don't need the session table below as describe in user guide

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(50) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter has the option of storing its "session" (Session to CodeIgniter actually means "cookie", but whatever) data server side in a database. The sessions table if for that. Personally, I've never found need for it -- encrypted cookies have worked just fine for me -- but if you'd like to learn more about it, check out the database section on the [CI_Session documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's helpful when your servers are behind load balancers or you are on a shared server.

Normal sessions are saved to files on disk, if using a shared server these could potentially be viewed by other users.

If you are behind a load balancer there is not an easy way to sync these files across multiple servers effectively losing sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you're using codeigniter's session library with a database and an authentication system you can do some cool stuff with it. specifically:

- you can log out users (can be useful in a situation where a forum user is banned but currently logged in)
- you can make users be logged in from one place at a time. I'd imagine this would very much suit an enterprise application